# Java output stream to subprocess flush results in IOException

Tags: java, exception, stream, output, flush

I have a subprocess receiving data from `stdin` line by line. Then it receives `$X$` line, it stops reading input streams, performs internal task on it, then exits. 
Now I wrote some tester for it:

```
public class MessageShowTester {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar \"/home/user/NetBeansProjects/MessageShow/dist/MessageShow.jar\"");
        p.getOutputStream().write("Hi\n$X$\n".getBytes());
        p.getOutputStream().flush();

    }

}
```

As the result I receive `IOException` on `p.getOutputStream().flush()`line. Much stranger is that another application I use the same construction doesn't share such behavior.

There is a limited version of MessageShow as example, that fails same way on tester, but works well from IDE.

```
public class MessageShow {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message="";
        String temp="";

        while(true)
        {
            temp = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();


            if("$X$".equals(temp)) break;


                message+=temp;
                message+="\n";


        }


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }

}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:315)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at messageshowtester.MessageShowTester.main(MessageShowTester.java:23)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Post the stack trace. Your question is meaningless without it.

Comment: Did you try it without the flush?

Answer (score 1):

If the subprocess finishes quickly, the parent process may not yet have done the flush. In this situation, the pipe between the processes has already been closed on the subprocess side and you'll see

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

or similar.

You shouldn't need the explicit flush. For passing a single line to a subprocess, consider a process parameter.

Less confident about what works and what not, but I have found that using

```
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( p.getOutputStream() );
    pw.println("hifile.dat");
    pw.println("$X$");
    pw.close();
```

succeeds in passing both lines to the subprocess.

In the subprocess,

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 while(true){
    temp = scanner.nextLine();
    if("$X$".equals(temp)) break;
    message+=temp;
}
```

is better than recreating a Scanner for each line, although it doesn't influence the fate of the subprocess.

Comment: No it won't. You will see 'connection reset' or 'broken pipe'. 'Stream closed' means that *you* closed the stream.

Comment: Well, subprocess has Scanner(System.in).nextLine() loop, reading as far as $X$ token passed as separate line, so the only thing used to shutdown the subprocess is this token. Also, direct use of subprocess from IDE works pretty well.

Comment: It crashes while executing flush - see your dump - how can it require flush and not require flush at the same time?